# Can't upload app to API 10 devices or emulator (stale dexed jars)

Tags: android, android-studio

I know that this question has been asked a lot on SO, but I tried almost every solution without success...

I have a problem when I try to upload my app to devices running on API 10 **(no problems with devices on API 11 and up)** with this error :

```
Installation failed since the device possibly has stale dexed jars that don't match the current version (dexopt error). In order to proceed, you have to uninstall the existing application.

WARNING: Uninstalling will remove the application data!

Do you want to uninstall the existing application?
```

If I click on "uninstall the app" (even if the app is not installed), it ends up with :

```
Unknown failure
```

It's not the problem related to 65K methods, since it works on every device except API 10. Nevertheless, I tried adding the multidex support and it didn't change anything...

It's not a problem of space either, since I deleted all the apps on my device before trying the installation. Plus the apk has a size of 12M...

- I tried to install the app on the emulator and it didn't work.
- I thought that it's an emulator problem, so I looked for a very old phone that I have running on Android 2.3.4 and tried to install the app on it and it didn't work.
- I tried to install the apk manually by copying the apk file to the sdk  directory and then install it directly on the emulator, but I have an error too.

**A very important thing** is that the app used to work fine before on the API 10 emulator, and stopped working one day without any significant change !

I've been struggling with this since two weeks now and it's so frustrating that I spent so much time on making my app compatible with API 10 only to be stuck with a problem like this !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I found a lot of solutions to this problem but none has worked in my case.

It turned out that I've changed the targeted SDK from 22 to 23, and that was the cause of this problem.

When I changed it back to 22, it worked !

I don't know why and I'm seriously thinking about changing the minimum SDK to 11 (I've put a lot of effort to be compatible with API 10, but I think that the users still with API 10 are rare and the effort is definitely not worth it).

Comment: unfortunately I have the same problem but changing the targeted SDK api level as suggested, didn't work for me. I'm your same situation except in my project I need multidex.